# root finding of f(x)=(1/2)|x| using Bisection search or newtons method

Tags: numerical-methods, roots, newton-raphson, bisection

Consider the function: f(x) = (1/2)|x|

Can we use bisection search to find one of its roots? Why or why not? 
Can we use Newton’s method to find one of its roots? Why or why not?

I do not quite understand when you can and can't use either of these algorithms. If anyone can answer this question and clear it up for me, I really appreciate it. Thanks!

Comment: Bisection needs continuity on some neighborhood of the root to be found, which you have here. Newton's method in principle needs continuous differentiability on some neighborhood of the root to be found in order for the usual proofs to go through, but in this special case you find that it works anyway.

Comment: @Ian awesome, that makes sense. Thank you

Comment: I don't think you can use Bisection method to find the root of function because your function is always positive (or I should say nonnegative ). So,  condition  $f(a)f(b)<0$ is never satisfied.

Comment: As OkkesDulgerci said, I was mistaken about bisection, which does need the sign to actually change in addition to needing continuity.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the bisection method, you should have $f(a) f(b) < 0$ which, together with the continuity of $f$ assures the convergence of the method. With that being said, bisection's method can converge even if the condition $f(a) f(b)<0$ is not satisfied. In the case of the specific function you mention, the convergence will depend on the actual implementation of the method, namely whether you test $f(a) f((a+b)/2) < 0$ or $f((a+b)/2) f(b) <0$. In the first case the method will not converge and in the second case it will (I am assuming that  $ab<0$).

Regarding Newton's method, it will kind of converge in a single iteration. if you choose any $x_0 \ne 0$, you will see that $x_1 = x_0 - \frac{f(x_0)}{f'(x_0)} = 0$, which is the actual solution. I say "kind of converge" because it would not be possible to further compute iterates...